# Cannot run multiple commands in one line

Tags: cmd, winscp

I am trying to run multiple commands in one line. The codes are below.

```
WinSCP.com
open user:pw@address
lcd C:\Users\xx\Desktop
get *.xlsx
exit
```

If I run them one by one, it will work. However, if I want to run them all together using one line, it will fail, no matter I am using `;` or `&`.

For example, if I run `WinSCP.com & open user:pw@address`, only the first part will be executed.

`WinSCP.com; open user:pw@address` doesn't work either.

How to execute them using one line?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening, because both command line and `winscp.com` are programs. When you're entering commands one by one you start `winscp.com` and next entered commands are going directly to the WinSCP. When you're trying to execute all commands at once it is starting WinSCP and waiting for it to finish and then executing next commands.

You definitely can create a text file with your commands and save it as `script.txt`

```
open user:pw@address
lcd C:\Users\xx\Desktop
get *.xlsx
exit
```

And then pass it to the `winscp.com` application like this:

```
winscp.com /script=script.txt
```

It may be possible to send all the commands at once by using `/command cmd1 cmd2 ...` where cmd1,2 are your commands, but it might be tricky.

**References**

- Command-line Options :: WinSCP

  - [Parameters](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/commandline#parameters)

Answer (score 0):

You can put the sequence of commands in a script file used by WinSCP and call it using the command sequence:

```
WinSCP.com /script="C:\Users\{name}\Documents\Scripts\{SomeFileName}.scp"
```

I have found it easier to keep track of what you are doing and keeps the command sequence easier to read.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I voted Andrew already. The reason that I put them in one line is I want to put them in VBA so user only needs to press the "button" once to load file.

Answer (score 0):

**These are all the possible ways of running multiple commands on a single line :**

When you use `command1 & command2` on the command prompt, it 
**executes the first command, and then the second command**.

`command1 && command2` it runs the first command, and then **runs the second command only if the first command completed successfully**.

`command1 || command2` it runs the first command, and then **runs the second command only if the first command did not complete successfully** (receives an error code greater than zero).

`(command1 & command2)` used to *group or nest multiple commands*.

***Since in your case, you want to run the first command and then do the other operation with-in it; it isn't possible to use any of the above.***

You have to write a script which you may call in the same line using a command.

You may do something like this : `(WinSCP.com /script=<script_path>) && exit`

*There are many more options in [WinSCP.com command](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/commandline).*